# How do I set up my navigation search bar in Swift to look like the Reddit App

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uisearchbar

I just started to learn how to code with Swift in Xcode, I need some help regarding the search bar. I want to add a search field bar to my navigation bar in center, and next to it i want to add two items . So far I managed to add a UISearch to my navigation bar but once I try to add items next to it, it pushes my icons above the search field.

Pressed State
[image: pressed state now of my search bar]

Normal State
[image: normal state of search bar]

Does anyone know what to add the two menu items next to it programmatically or in the storyboard? And how to make the search field centered and a bit thinner?

My code now:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.delegate = self as? UISearchControllerDelegate

    let searchBar = searchController.searchBar
    searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
    searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white

    if let textfield = searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField {
        textfield.textColor = UIColor.blue
        if let backgroundview = textfield.subviews.first {

            // Background color
            backgroundview.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

            // Rounded corner
            backgroundview.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
            backgroundview.clipsToBounds = true;
        }
    }

    if let navigationbar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar {
        navigationbar.barTintColor = UIColor.blue
    }

    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
    }
```

---

Reddit Example
[image: Reddit Example]

Comment: Can you please share screen shot?

Comment: @RJ168 just added two screenshots of how it looks now at the bottom of the post their is the reddit app one

Answer (score 1):

Okay, fixed it! Just used the code below. Now my next struggle is changing the background of the textfield.

```
//SEARCH
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self as? UISearchBarDelegate


    let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 44)
    let titleView = UIView(frame: frame)
    searchController.searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
    searchController.searchBar.frame = frame
    titleView.addSubview(searchController.searchBar)
    navigationItem.titleView = titleView

    }
```